# SQL query to get rows depending on month_year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a existing MySQL database with a column called month_year. It has date/time data in format like:- *1974 - 1982, 11/2001 - 2008, 03/2007 on, up to 1987 and 11/2001 - 02/2007.*

My website user will select a date and I need to give him some options depending on whether that date meets the criteria in DB.

for example:

```
up to 1987 in DB means all dates upto 1987
11/2001 - 2008 means all dates between this
03/2007 on - means all dates after this.
```

I need a SQL query to fetch all the rows matching this criteria. I think I need some regex to achieve this but am not sure. Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance.

**Added:** I do not have the choice to change the database. User will select year **2011** & month **10(October)**. Now I have to give him options based on his input. I will have to fetch all the rows whose month_year column satisfies this.

Column looks like this:

**month_year**

```
1974 - 1982
1988 - 10/1999
1988 - 10/1999
11/1999 - 10/2001
11/2001 - 2008
11/2001 - 2008
```

Comment: quote the values in the examples because we can't be sure what the values are.

Comment: @Webtecher: That's a bad idea in general. You're better off using native date/time types in the database so that you can use the database's native functions for dealing with dates and times. Using raw seconds-since-epoch also makes it harder for other software that has to access the database.

Comment: I know database should have used native date/time. But this is a customer requirement, he has an existing DB like this.

Comment: @mits Thanks for advise now i will change my db structure af fast as i can

Comment: @AJ. The only way to write a query that produces the result in no time, is by using two indexes date columns, one for the start date and one for the end date. It probably will be possible to solve it with the current structure, but querying that takes a long time and the time it takes increases with each row that is added.

Comment: Cant I use regex to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do this comparison using regexp's in not sensible.  You will get a very complicated regular expression that neither you nor anyone else will understand the next time you look at the code.

Instead, parse the strings into their components, and do the work on the components.  This generates longer code, but code that can be more easily followed.

What you have a "span" expression that you need to parse into the first and last dates.  Let me give you the solution in SQL Server.  I'm choosing this dialect simply because it is easier for me; I think you can readily adapt it to mysql (functions for dates and character strings seem to have different names in each database).

The following query adds columns month1, year1, month2, and year2 to the data:

```
select t.*,
       (case when charindex('/', part1) > 0 -- have month or not?
             then cast(left(part1, charindex('/', part1)) as int)
             else 1
        end) as Month1,
       (case when charindex('/', part1) > 0 -- have month or not?
             then cast(substring(part1, charindex('/', part1), 100) as int)
             else cast(part1 as int)
        end) as Year1,
       (case when charindex('/', part2) > 0 -- have month or not?
             then cast(left(part2, charindex('/', part2)) as int)
             else 1
        end) as Month2,
       (case when charindex('/', part2) > 0 -- have month or not?
             then cast(substring(part2, charindex('/', part2), 100) as int)
             else cast(part2 as int)
        end) as Year2
from (select t.*,
             left(t.span, charindex(t.span, '-')-2) as part1,
             substring(t.span, charindex(t.span, '-')+2) as part2
      from t
     )
```

You can now use these expressions to do the comparisons that you want.  With one caveat:  the mixing of years and years with months may give unexpected results.  You need to be particular careful when a user specifies something like 9/2008 - 2010.  Is this all months in 2010?  Or just the first month?

Comment: Frankly I have not understood this in first read. Does this solution mean adding more column to the DB and population it correctly with the existing data?

Comment: You could add separate columns for the two dates.  However, this solution is about adding them on the fly, when you need to for querying purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month_year="1974 - 1982"
```

Changing the "1974 - 1982" to suit the other values. Although that seems so obvious, there must be something more to this?!

Comment: That will find `"1974 - 1982"` but nt `"1974 - 1981"` nor `"1975 - 1981"` nor `"1975 - 1982"`

Comment: exactly! Arjan is right! but I do need something like this only.